One way ANOVA on compliance rates (by time period) with different lengths
I'm stumped a little on this, as in my stats classes we had very nicely packaged data with nice, normal data that was easy to understand! Apologies if this seems totally obvious.
My data is a series of compliance rates among several categories of staff over several audit periods (AP). We'll say the action they are supposed to perform is swiping a card when they arrive at work. Compliance rate is, of course, # of times they actually swiped the card / # of times they were expected to.
I have three date groups to compare, but all of them vary in length, as we're trying to show during and post-COVID compliance. Data is measured every four months, so there are three APs in a year, starting in November:

AP 1: 1 November to 31 March
AP 2: 1 April to 30 June
AP 3: 1 July to 31 October

I'm observing the data from November 2018 to October 2022, split as such:
Date Group 1 (pre-COVID, baseline/control):

AP-1, November 2018 - 31 March 2019
AP-2, 1 April 2019 - 30 June 2019
AP-3, 1 July 2019 - 31 October 2019
AP-1, 1 November 2019 - 31 March 2020 [12 months, 4 periods total]

Date Group 2 (COVID):

AP-2, 1 April 2020 - 30 June 2020
AP-3, 1 July 2020 - 31 October 2020
AP-1, 1 November 2020 - 31 March 2021
AP-2, 1 April 2021 - 30 June 2021
AP-3, 1 July 2021 - 31 October 2021 [20 months, 5 periods total]

Date Group 3 (post-covid):

AP-1, 1 November 2021 - 31 March 2022
AP-2, 1 April 2022 - 31 June 2022
AP-3, 1 July 2022 - 31 October 2022 [9 months, 3 periods total]

The data looks something like this for all categories of staff combined.



Group
AP code
Card swiped
Total entries
Compliance




1
2019-1
1019
1231
0.790


1
2019-2
782
878
0.788


1
2019-3
934
1132
0.793


1
2020-1
973
1151
0.821


2
2020-2
640
749
0.834


2
2020-3
901
1075
0.810


2
2021-1
952
1122
0.816


2
2021-2
674
807
0.800


2
2021-3
841
1001
0.804


3
2022-1
727
857
0.820


3
2022-2
733
887
0.784


3
2022-3
868
1041
0.801



I want to use ANOVA to see if there was a significant different in compliance rate from date group 1 (pre-COVID) to date groups 2 and 3 (COVID and post-COVID). Would using one-way ANOVA be the solution? Asking because I'm not accustomed to dealing with rates, rather "here's how long the leaf petals are." Working in R if that helps. Thanks heaps!

Would it make sense to frame this as a longitudinal data analysis rather than analyzing overall compliance.

As per the previous answer, yes, you can use an ANOVA (DV=compliance, continuous variable; IV=Group, catehorical, with 3 levels).
But... Your sample size is very small (4, 5 and 3). It is unlikely you have enough power to find any significant difference.
Even for some form of regression analysis, the sample size is limited.
I assume the compliance value is an aggregate value, over many employees? Can you access the compliance data per employee? Or per employee group? This would give you a (much?) larger sample size in each group, and hence a better chance of seeing a difference (if it is there).

Unfortunately not, the best we have are the counts of people who did the action over that audit period, not the specific person. (Confidentiality and all that, apparently.)
We can compare between each staffing group over the audit periods, rather than the entire collective of employees. I'll play around with the data and see what pops. :) Thank you!

You could do an ANOVA of
lm(compliance ~ group)

and then create a contrast of 1 vs. 2 and 3.
This answers your question as posed. But you might consider using period (or even month), as opposed to group and then using a spline of period. This would let you see whether things changed at specific points, and how those relate to COVID.
Not only does this allow a finer look at what was going on, but it also does not categorize COVID as "pre" "in" and "post". I think that categorization is a bad idea. Reactions to COVID, and rules about it, and so on all changed continuously. E.g. people didn't wake up on Nov. 1 and say "oh good! COVID is over! Let's all go back to normal."
